# -Error: Subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector

Tags: c

I have to find the number of words which have a certain character in them, what I get from the arguments. I have to work with general input. I made a function but it won't work. I don't know how to work with arguments properly.

```
void function(char *argv) {
   char x;
   int c,i;
   x = argv[1][0] ;
   i = 0;
   while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
      if(c == x)
         ++i;
   }
   printf("%d \n",i);
}
```

Comment: What errors do you get? They can help in finding out what is wrong.

Comment: You need to read a beginner C book **and pay attention.**

Comment: Since this is an exercise I'll try to guide you toward the answer.`x = argv[1][0] ;` This is not correct, `argV` is supposed to be an 1-dimensional array of characters but what you have here is how you handle a 2-dimensional array. One of your problems is this, try to fix your code line by line and understand exactly what you're doing.

Comment: It's a beginner-level question, but it's definitely not a "gimmecodez": OP put in some genuine effort before asking for help. Voting to re-open.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `argv` is the same as what is passed to `main`, your function declaration is incorrect: it needs to be

```
void function(char *argv[]) {
    ... //              ↑↑
}
```

Now you can treat `argv` as an array of arrays of characters, with two subscript operators.

Of course since you are not using any part of `argv` beyond the first character of the first parameter, you might as well accept a single `char`, and let the caller decide which `char it's going to be:

```
void function(char x) {
    ...
}
...
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    ... // Check argc...
    function(argv[1][0]);
}
```

Comment: I just love this ↑...

Comment: @user2975913 You are welcome! Take a look at the edit, passing a single `char` lets you keep the work with command line attributes in `main`, without "spilling" it into your other functions.